# SUM of numbers from while while

Tags: php, sql

I try to take Sum from table when prices is different but I get only one price sum.
[table of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjj17.png)

```
   $db = ("SELECT distinct price FROM `tests`  order by price desc  ");
   $resultprice  = $conn->query($db);
   while ($rowprice = mysqli_fetch_array($resultprice ))
   {   
   $rowprice=$rowprice['price'];
   $db = ("SELECT sum(amount) FROM `tests` where  price='$rowprice'");
   $resultamount  = $conn->query($db);
   while ($rowamount = mysqli_fetch_array($resultamount ))
   {   
     $pamount=$rowamount[0];
     echo $rowprice; echo "<br>";
     $sumprice=($rowprice-"70")*$pamount;
   }    
   echo $sumprice;
   }
```

Comment: If you're having trouble with the result, try to separate the problem into parts.  Ask the SQL question first, with just enough data to show that SQL problem.

Comment: in database i have several products with diferent pricess that i sold. i need to to take information how much monay i done after sold product.

Comment: Your question contains no detail about products.  Please add that detail (to the question) if your question involves products.  Try to clarify the complete question and, if possible, restrict the problem to SQL, if your current issue is about the SQL.  The current answer should already address the existing question.  Did you try it?  Create a complete (but minimal) test case that shows your table(s), the test data, your actual result and the (goal) expected result.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really need to loop in a program to do this one. Use `GROUP BY` instead.

```
SELECT price
     , sum(amount)
  FROM `tests`
 GROUP BY price
 ORDER BY price
;
```

If the `tests` table contains sold product detail, we can calculate the total sum of each product sold, like this:

```
SELECT product
     , sum(amount) AS total
  FROM tests
 GROUP BY product
 ORDER BY sum(amount)
;
```